# WPF ComboBox SelectedValue binding not updated when selection is changed

Tags: wpf, combobox, telerik, selectedvalue

I have a Telerik RadComboBox set up like:

```
<t:RadComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="customer" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"
               SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
               SelectionChanged="customer_SelectionChanged_1"/>
```

The combo is properly populated, but if I click the drop down and select an item from the list, the `SelectedValue` property is not updated.  If I begin typing in the combo and select an item that way, the `SelectedValue` property is not updated.  **BUT** if I use the mouse wheel, or the arrow keys, then the `SelectedValue` property *is* properly updated.

I added the `SelectionChanged` event in the code behind so I could look at the properties of the control (this application is using an MVVM pattern) and it looks like that even when the `SelectedItem` property *is* set to a valid item, the `SelectedValue` property is null.  If I use the mouse wheel to scroll down to an item, then both properties are properly set as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is caused by the fact that my view model returns `Guid.Empty` by default when there is no selection.  But since there isn't an item in the list that has an `Id` property of `Guid.Empty` the control gets confused.

Adding the attribute: `SelectedIndex="0"` fixes this.

Comment: This got me as well.. I was using `SelectedValue=null` when nothing was selected (with `SelectedValuePath` set to 'Name'), and this caused the 'control to get confused' as you say, so I switched to using `SelectedItem` and everything seems to work.